# execvp didn't pass args to called program

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I want to load a new program by fork and exec, and pass args to the new program.
But I was failed.

```
//fork_exec.c
int main()
{
    char *args[] = {"/home"};
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
    case -1:
        return;
    case 0://child
        execvp("ls",args);
        _exit(1);
    default://parent
        return;
    }
}
```

I compile the file fork_exec.c then get a file a.out.
Then I type

> ./a.out

in the terminate.I suggested that a list of files in the /home will be shown on the screen.
But the shown files war fork_exec.c and a.out in fact.
So I guess that the args was not passed to the ls program successfully.
Please someone tell me what happened and why.
Thanks.

Comment: Please read the man page for [`execvp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) carefully, in particular the requirements on the array.

Comment: From man page of `execvp`: "The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer" .have you try with `char *args[] = { "ls","/home",NULL};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char * args[] = {"ls","/home/",NULL};
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
    case -1:
        return;
    case 0://child
        execvp(args[0],args);
        _exit(1);
    default://parent
        return;
    }
}
```

This works. Try out and read its MAN page.